# How to Query Wikivoyage Destinations

Tags: api, mediawiki

I am trying to get a JSON list of all destinations listed on Wikivoyage: https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Destinations

I have tried using the wikivoyage API sandbox but I have been unable to identify how a "destination" is differentiated in the code.

I have searched the Wikivoyage API sandbox for a couple of days but I have not found any datapoint relating to destination. https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox

The closest thing I have found is that on the destinations page (https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Destinations) a summary count of 31,721 is listed, which, when clicked on, appears to list all content pages(https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Special:Statistics).

But I have yet to discover how to list all content pages via the API as this too seems not to be an internal datapoint against which one can filter.

I would be very appreciative of any help!

Comment: What code? Or are you expecting it to be written for you? You should show what you have done so far.

Comment: Using the API URL such as: https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?&action=query&list=allpages

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to identify destinations using the API...that is why I did not post it. Sorry!

Comment: It looks like https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Category:All_destination_articles might be relevant. If so it is trivial to get all the titles inside the category.